# Random failed/completed execution of simple Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I had a time-based script that for a couple months stopped functioning without an apparent reason. I made a simple test script to try and detect a problem. When I run it, sometimes it completes and sometimes it fails. Cell A1 in "test" sheet contains a date/time stamp.

```
function cycle4(){
  var report = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXX");
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(report);
  Logger.log(report);
  var test = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("test");
  test.activate();
      var timestamp = report.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1).getValue();
      var rdateold = new Date(timestamp);
      var curtime = new Date();
      var hdiff = Math.floor((curtime-rdateold)/(3600*1000));
      Logger.log(rdateold);
      Logger.log(curtime);
      Logger.log(hdiff);
}
```

Just now, I ran the script three times almost in a row with Completed-Failed-Completed result.

It always fails with this:
Exception: Document XXXX is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)
at cycle4(Code:180:40)

And, when it completes, it's taking an awful long time to do this, like 167 seconds. It takes 80-90 seconds to read the sheet, then it takes 70-100 seconds to retrieve the date/time stamp from cell A1 and perform simple calculations.

Any ideas why this unpredictable behavior, odd reason of not being able to access the file, and super slow execution?

Comment: Can you share the time trigger settings from your existing script, also include the execution log error.

Comment: The current test script is not time-based. It is a simple test script to try to diagnose the problem. The main time-based script runs every two hours. The error message for the main script is the same:
Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id XXXX.
There seems to be an issue with the api access to the main file which works or doesn't work randomly and when it works, it takes a very long time.

Comment: l would just move to another spreadsheet.

Comment: I did to test it. When the sheet is empty, it takes 2 seconds to run the script. But when I copy the entire workbook with all the tabs and run the same script, the initial API call takes 80 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the issue was that the preadsheet was too heavy - it had lots of "Today()" and "Importrange" functions. After cleaning all those up, the api access time returned to normal.